# Ignore empty elements from json body using jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am constructing a json body using jackson in java. It would be something like the below

```
{
   "subject": "math",
    "marks": "100",
    "student":{
        "name": "x",
        "class": "8"
    }
 }
```

Based on different REST URI's the json body has to ignore some fields or elements. How do I Ignore the "student" part from the above json body using jackson? 
When I ignore it I should be able to get only

```
{ "subject": "math", "marks": "100"}
```

**but am getting it as below which is incorrect-**

```
{ "subject": "math", "marks": "100","student":{}}
```

I have two classes with getters and setters, one as subject and the other as student. I tried using @JsonIgnore but it ignores all the URI's, which I don't want. I also tried @JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY). How do I achieve this?

Am adding my code here. Based on different REST URI's the json body has to ignore some fields or elements.Example for one URI, it should include all the fields , for another it should ignore student. 
       Score score = new Score();

```
    score.setSubject("math");
    score.setMarks("100");

    Score.Student student =score.new Student();
    score.setStudent(student);

    switch (type) {
    case StudentAdd:
        score.setSubject("math");
        score.setMarks("100");
        break;
    case StudentDelete:
        score.setSubject("math");
        score.setMarks("100");
        break;
    case StudentComplete:
        score.setChangeReason("C");

    default:
        break;
        score.setSubject("math");
        score.setMarks("100");

    score.setStudent(student);

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
    //objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
    objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_EMPTY);

    StringWriter jsonBody = new StringWriter();
    objectMapper.writeValue(jsonBody, score);

    return jsonBody.toString();
}

    //@JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)
    class Score {

        private String subject;
        private String marks;
        private Student student;

        public String getSubject() {
            return subject;
        }

        public void setSubject(String subject) {
            this.subject = subject;
        }

        public String getMarks() {
            return marks;
        }

        public void setMarks(String marks) {
            this.marks = marks;
        }

        public Student getStudent() {
            return student;
        }

        public void setStudent(Student student) {
            this.student = student;
        }

    //@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
    class Student {

        private String name;

        @JsonProperty("class")
        private String clazz;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getClazz() {
            return clazz;
        }

        public void setClazz(String clazz) {
            this.clazz = clazz;
        }

}
    }
   }
     }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jackson Different JSONFilter same Class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27041544/jackson-different-jsonfilter-same-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

This posts seems to be a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27041544/jackson-different-jsonfilter-same-class).

**EDIT 2**

Use @JsonView instead of @JsonFilter

Below is sample code that uses @JsonView to print different views of the same JSON object:

> {"subject":"math","marks":"100"}

and

> {"subject":"math","marks":"100","student":{"name":"x","class":"8"}}

```
public class Views {
    public static class Filtered {}
    public static class All extends Filtered {}
}

public class Student {
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty("class")
    private String clazz;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getClazz() {
        return clazz;
    }

    public void setClazz(String clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }
}

public class Score {
    @JsonView(Views.Filtered.class)
    private String subject;

    @JsonView(Views.Filtered.class)
    private String marks;

    @JsonView(Views.All.class)
    private Student student;

    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public String getMarks() {
        return marks;
    }

    public void setMarks(String marks) {
        this.marks = marks;
    }

    public Student getStudent() {
        return student;
    }

    public void setStudent(Student student) {
        this.student = student;
    }
}

public class JsonTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        Student student = new Student();
        student.setName("x");
        student.setClazz("8");

        Score score = new Score();
        score.setSubject("math");
        score.setMarks("100");
        score.setStudent(student);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        //do not serialize student property
        System.out.println(mapper.writerWithView(Views.Filtered.class).writeValueAsString(score));

        //also serialize student property
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(score));
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the above reply. The above answer works. But am looking for something where the json body changes based on the requested URI. Example for one URI I need to include everything from student and score in the json body, for another URI I need to exclude the student. I edited my question above with my code.

Comment: Your comment is not clear to me.  I changed the code to use \@JsonView instead if \@JsonFilter, which would result in cleaner code.  I assume each URI is bound to a web service method.  These methods can each use a different view?

Answer (score 3):

This can be configured on annotation using `JsonInclude` with value of `NON_NULL` rather than `NON_EMPTY`.

The Javadoc for NON_EMPTY vs NON_NULL is less than clear, but my experiments show that using NON_NULL works as you're expecting using Jackson 2.6.2.

```
@JsonProperty
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
private Student student;
```

Example

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(new Foo(100, new Student("bob"), "math")));
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(new Foo(100, null, "math")));
```

Output

```
{"marks":100,"subject":"math","student":{"name":"bob"}}
{"marks":100,"subject":"math"}
```

Note this can also be set globally using

```
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
```

Comment: I have NON_NULL in place, it works for some and doesn't work for other.  Ex: my original json is something like this--{
   "subject": "math",
    "marks": "100",
    "student":{
        "name": "x",
        "class": "8"
    ,"schoolList": [{"school": "abc"}]
 } @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL) is able to ignore the "schoolList" but not "student"

Answer (score 0):

Set `WRITE_NULL_MAP_VALUES` to false in your ObjectMapper.

Code:

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.WRITE_NULL_MAP_VALUES, false);
```